# STM32 NUCLEO F303RE : LED2 does not turn on (nor blink)

Tags: stm32, blink

I have a STM32 NUCLEO F303RE board.

According to the reference and user manual, there is only one user LED (LED2 corresponding to PA5) that can be used. LED3 is red (means power OK AFAIU) and LED1 is red (after red-and-green blinking during flashing - means flash OK AFAIU as I get the message `Flash written and verified! jolly good!`).

So, according to the doc, it seems the board is OK as LED1 and LED3 are red. But the (green) LED2 doesn't blink. I simplified the code to suppress the blinking and just try to turn the LED2 ON: the LED does **not** turn ON?!

Here is the blink-reduced code:

```
>> cat blink.c
#include "stm32f3xx.h"

int main() {
  SystemInit();

  // Turn on clock on GPIOA.
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;

  // Set PA5 (GPIOA, Pin 5) to output mode.
  GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1;
  GPIOA->MODER |=  GPIO_MODER_MODER5_0;

  // Set PA5 (GPIOA, Pin 5) output mode to push-pull.
  GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~GPIO_OTYPER_OT_5;

  // Set PA5 (GPIOA, Pin 5) speed to high.
  GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5_1;
  GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5_0;

  // Set PA5 (GPIOA, Pin 5) pull-up and pull-down.
  GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR5_1;
  GPIOA->PUPDR |= ~GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR5_0;

  // Initialize: turn ON the LED connected to PA5.
  //GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_5; // LED2 does not turn ON?!
  GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_5; // LED2 does not turn ON?!

  return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong? Or what did I miss?

**EDIT**

I'am new to all STM related stuffs: I know programming well, but, not used to electronics / hardware... So some electronics / hardware related problems look like black-box to me! Could you elaborate on these topics?

> can't know what the systeminit code does and what happens if you immediately return after turning it on

OK, make sense. I added `while(1) {};` before `return 0` at the end of `main` to make sure the main thread is kept alive: same result, LED2 does **not** turn ON.

> Have you debugged the code in any way?

No idea how... Would be glad to be able to! This is my very-very-very first try with STM card so I am not sure how to do this (my understanding is that you need UART to get `printf` debug messages back on PC - no idea how to "debug a code running on a card", if you could elaborate on this I would be glad to know).

> Check the solder bridges.
> SB21 should be closed for LD2 to work.

Can you elaborate on this?

At software side, I'm quite experienced, but, at hardware side, I am baby-stepping!... Didn't even know what SB existed! :)

After googling a bit, I would say there is no way to "close SB21" by programming: code can not make this, right? To "close SB21", my understanding is that I need to **physically** solder 2 pads on the board (I don't have a solder iron): is this correct? Do I need to **physically** solder SB21 on the board, or, is there a way to "make this SB21 closure by **code**" (programing only - if yes what is the code for this)?

> Have you tried to setup an STM32CubeIDE project to turn LD2 on

Linux based. Not yet.

**EDIT**

I have checked SB21 is closed (pads soldered on the card). LED doesn't turn on nor blink

Comment: Check the solder bridges. And on some boards LED is not PA5, so double check the manual for that too. But we can't know what the systeminit code does and what happens if you immediately return after turning it on, you might not see it if MCU reboots after return. Have you debugged the code in any way?

Comment: SB21 should be closed for LD2 to work.

Comment: Have you tried to setup an STM32CubeIDE project to turn LD2 on?

Comment: Try without calling SystemInit(). Also, try pressing the RESET button.

Comment: @wek without SystemInit and/or pressing RESET doesn't help